# MySql localhost hosting error on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: php, mysql, database, macos, phpmyadmin

I'm sitting on a MacOS High Sierra(v10.13.1) and I followed a guide to install/enable Apache2, PHP7, MySQL and PhpMyAdmin locally.
The guide I followed:

```
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13/).
```

I thought everything worked since I can log in to PhpMyAdmin with my root account and have access to create databases etc.. But trying to connect to my database in PHP I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/.../Sites/BattleriteTracker/include/base/Database.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/.../Sites/BattleriteTracker/include/base/Database.php on line 7
Mysql connection error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The code I used to connect with:

```
$Adress = "localhost";
$User = "root";
$Password = "...";
$Name = "BattleriteTracker";

$Connect = new mysqli($Name, $User, $Password, $Name);

if($Connect->connect_errno)
{
    die("Mysql connection error: " . $Connect->connect_error);
}
```

Some additional info about my versions:

```
Apache: 2.4.27
MySQL: 5.7.20
PhpMyAdmin: 4.7.5
```

If anyone of you know what the problem is, please enlighten me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You pass the ```$Name``` as database host, you should pass  ```$Adress``` instead. ```new mysqli($Adress, $User, $Password, $Name);```

Comment: Jesus christ, Ive been trying to figure out if my mysql.socket wasnt found by php and vice versa for two days, can't believe I accedentaly sent in the wrong variable. Sometimes all it takes is a pare of fresh eyes to fix the problem :X SOrry for my stupidity, and thank you for seeing what I couldnt.